# How do I unlock a Thinkpad A20?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2000

I inherited an IBM Thinkpad A20 type 2628 laptop. I have no recovery disc, no manuals, nothing that can be considered "directions" of any kind.

The computer has a picture of a padlock when you start it up.The padlock is closed(I assume it means the computer is locked). There is nothing I can do with it being locked.I can not get into bios, safe mode, command prompt, I can do nothing until I get this thing unlocked.

My question is, how do I unlock it or bypass it to get it unlocked?
I have an ASUS computer that works perfectly so if that helps any...

Answer (score 0):

If the default override password doesn't work (it's `merlin`), you're out of luck. The security is a physical chip soldered to the motherboard. The hard drive is encrypted and locked as well.

Comment: TY Sir, but that did not work & I refuse to give up...not giving up yet anyway...I'll put it up for now(as I am very frustrated) and try again later...maybe something will come to mind.  TY Again Sir.